# telerik как заполнить grid по событию нажатия на row другого grid

Tags: update, grid, telerik

Добрый день,

может кто сталкивался и подскажет.

Есть два telerik grid на странице, нужно при нажатии на строке первого grid
обновлять второй данными из запроса в БД. Соответственно у меня получилось отлавливать событие нажатия нужной строки, брать его id  и передавать в controll для формирования запроса в БД для отображения нужной информации во втором grid.

Но дальше не понимаю как мне полученный результат json моего controll присвоить как новый источник данных для второго грида и обновить его.

Подскажите кто сталкивался, спасибо!

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onButtonClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var grid = $("#grid1").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        $.ajax({
            url: "/myControll/ReadDataMethod",
            type: "GET",
            data: { id: selectedItem.Id}
        }).done(function(returnData) {
            $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(returnData);
        $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение следующее!

По событию клика по строке первого грида, заполняем скрытые поля нашими значениями переменных, которые будут переданы в контрол и вызываем метод Read второго грида.

```
<input type="hidden" id="HiInIncId" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" id="HiInIncNum" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onChange(e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());

        $('input[id=HiInIncId]').val(selectedItem.Id);
        $('input[id=HiInIncNum]').val(selectedItem.IncidentID);

        $("#gridInc").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    }
</script>
```

Во втором гриде указываем Data("extraDataInc") для вызова скрипта передачи наших переменных в контрол.

```
Read(action => action.Action("ReadIncident", "DetailInc").Data("extraDataInc")).

<script type="text/javascript">
    function extraDataInc(e) {
        return {
            someDate: $('#someDate').val(),
            incid: $('input[id=HiInIncId]').val(),
            incnum: $('input[id=HiInIncNum]').val()
        }
    }
</script>
```